# cURL to DropBox using Symfony 3

Tags: php, ssl, curl, docker, symfony

I use the [Gaufrette Bundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle) of Symfony to access DropBox API.
The code in my controller is

```
$dropbox = $this->get('acme.dropbox.api');
$dropbox->getAccountInfo();
```

I get an error

> Curl error: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
>   CAfile: rootca
>   CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
>   500 Internal Server Error - Dropbox_Exception_NotFound

I used Docker so I'm not sure if it's with the way I configured the certificates on my Docker. I used the https://github.com/eko/docker-symfony bundle for Docker.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was it couldn't find the certificate file.

```
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt");
```

On my docker box the certificates are in folder /etc/ssl/certs and I had to write the file extension as well.